# Why is git saying these attributes are not valid attributes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, gitattributes

I'm using the default .gitattributes file for my Visual Studio project on github but whenever I try to commit it throws back "not a valid attribute" errors.

The errors are for lines 1,12,20, 21, and 24. What is most confusing to me is that most of the lines returning errors are commented out.

Here is the file

```
**###############################################################################**
# Set default behavior to automatically normalize line endings.
###############################################################################
* text=auto

###############################################################################
# Set default behavior for command prompt diff.
#
# This is need for earlier builds of msysgit that does not have it on by
# default for csharp files.
# Note: This is only used by command line
**###############################################################################**
#*.cs     diff=csharp

###############################################################################
# Set the merge driver for project and solution files
#
# Merging from the command prompt will add diff markers to the files if there
# are conflicts (Merging from VS is not affected by the settings below, in VS
**# the diff markers are never inserted). Diff markers may cause the following** 
**# file extensions to fail to load in VS. An alternative would be to treat**
# these files as binary and thus will always conflict and require user
# intervention with every merge. To do so, just uncomment the entries below
**###############################################################################**
#*.sln       merge=binary
#*.csproj    merge=binary
#*.vbproj    merge=binary
#*.vcxproj   merge=binary
#*.vcproj    merge=binary
#*.dbproj    merge=binary
#*.fsproj    merge=binary
#*.lsproj    merge=binary
#*.wixproj   merge=binary
#*.modelproj merge=binary
#*.sqlproj   merge=binary
#*.wwaproj   merge=binary

###############################################################################
# behavior for image files
#
# image files are treated as binary by default.
###############################################################################
#*.jpg   binary
#*.png   binary
#*.gif   binary

###############################################################################
# diff behavior for common document formats
# 
# Convert binary document formats to text before diffing them. This feature
# is only available from the command line. Turn it on by uncommenting the 
# entries below.
###############################################################################
#*.doc   diff=astextplain
#*.DOC   diff=astextplain
#*.docx  diff=astextplain
#*.DOCX  diff=astextplain
#*.dot   diff=astextplain
#*.DOT   diff=astextplain
#*.pdf   diff=astextplain
#*.PDF   diff=astextplain
#*.rtf   diff=astextplain
#*.RTF   diff=astextplain
```

Comment: we can't see the line numbers, can you better highlight the problem lines?

Comment: yes I just made them all bold.

Comment: That asterisk that is the first character or two characters in each of the problem lines is the issue.

Comment: @DavidTansey those asterisks are only there as a result of the formatting to make the lines bold

Comment: Sorry.  Can you use NotePad++ or similar to check what type of line-endings exist on those problem lines?  i.e. are the line-endings `CRLF` or just `LF`?

Comment: I checked and all the line endings were CRLF. I actually dont know what was wrong. I just created a new .gitattributes file. I pasted the same contents into it and it works. This is still really confusing to me.